# How to insert a column with data using Google Sheets API?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following code with which i am trying to insert a column

```
var updateData = {
            range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}`,
            majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
            values: [["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"], ["Test5"]],
          }

const apiBody = {
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    data: updateData,
  };
var result = await fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values:batchUpdate`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(apiBody),
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Update Cell Error: ", error);
    });
```

The above code gives me TypeError:

Please note that I use R1C1 notation in range instead of A1 notation as my column index are dynamically generated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use R1C1 as the range of Sheets API, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var updateData = {
            range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}`,
            majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
            values: [["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"], ["Test5"]],
          }
```

#### To:

```
var ar = [["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"], ["Test5"]];
var updateData = {
  range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}:R1C${index + 1 + ar.length}`,
  majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
  values: ar,
};
```

- By this, if `index` is 1, the values of `Test1` to `Test5` are put into cells "B1:F1".
- In this modification, your access token can be used for updating your Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result. About `I have the following code with which i am trying to insert a column`, if you want to put your values as one column, how about the following modification? By this, when `index` is 1, the values of `Test1` to `Test5` are put into cells "B1:B5".

  ```js
  var ar = [["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"], ["Test5"]];
  var updateData = {
    range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}:R${ar.length + 1}C${index + 1}`,
    majorDimension: "ROWS",
    values: ar,
  };
  ```
- The whole modified script using the 1st modification is as follows.

```js
var ar = [["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"], ["Test5"]];
var updateData = {
  range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}:R1C${index + 1 + ar.length}`,
  majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
  values: ar,
};

const apiBody = {
  valueInputOption: "RAW",
  data: updateData,
};
var result = await fetch(
  `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}/values:batchUpdate`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(apiBody),
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Update Cell Error: ", error);
  });
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. your second solution worked perfectly with a little modification. range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}:R${ar.length + 1}C${index + 1}` should be range: `${sheetName}!R1C${index + 1}:R${ar.length}C${index + 1}`

Comment: This solution appends columns to the end. Is it possible to insert a column with data between existing columns?

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Is it possible to insert a column with data between existing columns?`, I think that it's yes. If you want to achieve this, I think that after a new column was inserted with [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), the above script can be used. In that case, it is required to use the gridRange instead of R1C1. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike for the suggestion. I'll try this method and update you. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. When you insert a new column, I think that you can use [InsertDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Tanaike...is it possible to use sheetName instead of sheetId in InsertDimensionRequest ?

Comment: @Safi About your new question of `is it possible to use sheetName instead of sheetId in InsertDimensionRequest ?`, I think that it's not. Unfortunately, in this case, it is required to use the sheet ID instead of the sheet name. I apologize for this specification.

Comment: No need to apologise @Tanaike. I understand, I have modified my code to use sheetId. Thank you for your time and effort to answer/solve users' questions!!

Comment: @Safi Thank you for replying. When you want to convert the sheet name to the sheet ID, I think that ["Method: spreadsheets.get"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) can be used.

Comment: Yes @Tanaike I did that. Thank you!

Comment: the InsertDimensionRequest gives me empty "replies" and column not getting inserted {spreadsheetId: '1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM', replies: Array(1)}
replies: 
Array(1)
0: {}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]
: Array(0)
spreadsheetId: "1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: @Safi About your new issue of `the InsertDimensionRequest gives me empty "replies" and column not getting inserted {spreadsheetId: '1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM', replies: Array(1)} replies: Array(1) 0: {} length: 1 [[Prototype]] : Array(0) spreadsheetId: "1b_H4613iP99BpKSatpKz79bEinCP9mplntf8Yf_P_zM" [[Prototype]]: Object`,  I would like to support you.

Comment: @Safi But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: this is my Api const insertApi = await fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}:batchUpdate`, options); and body { requests: [ {
      insertDimension: {
        range: {
          sheetId: tabId,
          dimension: "COLUMNS",
          startIndex: index + 1,
          endIndex: index + 2,
        },
        inheritFromBefore: true,
      },
    }]}

Comment: I understand @Tanaike..I'll post separately Thank you!